# What is the name for a 'map' that 'expands' instead of one to one

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

For example

```
a = [{foo: '1', things:[1,2]},{foo: '2', things:[3,4]}]
b = someFunction(a)
```

contents of b is now:

```
[{foo: '1', thing: 1}, {foo: '1', thing: 2},
 {foo: '2', thing: 3}, {foo: '2', thing: 4}]
```

Wherein bar is is derived from each element in things, but 'things' could just as easily be an array of objects that I want to combine with outside properties of the object {foo: '1',........,arraOfThings: [] }

Is there a name for this?

Comment: The concept is a `mapMany` which isn't built into js, but you can get around it with a `map` that produces arrays, followed by a `reduce` that concats them.

Comment: ah thanks, i had written it, i just didn't know what to call it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) in the functional programming language Haskell.